# what is the entry point to python source code

Tags: python, cpython

i am trying to understand how python works. so, i took fork of official python repository which is available at the following [Link](https://github.com/python/cpython). I am a beginner c programmer. but, i understand that main is the entry point to the application. Since python is written in `c, c++`, for which `main` is the entry point, can anyone help me which file has the `main` function. so, when i run `python.exe`, which function is first executed taking all the command line arguments?

**NOTE**: i am not asking for an entry point to a  python program. I know compiler just starts executing line by line. What i want to know is, when we run a code, which function in python source code actually takes the entire python code interprets it and give a result.

Comment: I misunderstood the qs. Hence deleted the answer.

Comment: maybe make the question clearer instead of having to clarify something different in the description

Comment: @L_Church,  i just edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the file `Programs/python.c` . https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Programs/python.c

As you can see, the only thing it does is call another function, which you can find here. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/main.c

The code that parses command-line arguments is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/main.c#L2601

Note that github has a search facility, so you can search for "main" or "_Py_UnixMain" and find references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just have one more doubt, can i place a debug point and look through the execution in c program just like how we debug python code?

Comment: @InAFlash yes, you can use a debugger to debug c, if you compile the code with debug symbols. You can use gdb if you're using unix.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is [this file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Programs/python.c) that you're looking for:

```
/* Minimal main program -- everything is loaded from the library */

#include "Python.h"

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
#else
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return _Py_UnixMain(argc, argv);
}
#endif
```